# button inside border

Tags: c#, wpf, button, border

I have a problem with a button inside a border. I want the button to fill the button space inside a border but the button is placed above the border and not under the border. And this way it hides the corder radius made by the border.

Here is a picture of my problem:

[image]

Someone knows how to put the button below the border?

Here is my xaml for my button:

```xml
<Button Name="filterCustomerBtn" 
        Command="{Binding Path=UpdateDepartments}" 
        Style="{StaticResource defaultButtonStyle}" 
        Width="200" 
        Margin="0, 15, 0, 0" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">Filter now</Button>
```

Here is the relevant xaml code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="defaultButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}" Margin="2" Background="LightBlue">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Name="filterCustomerBtn" Command="{Binding Path=UpdateDepartments}" Style="{StaticResource defaultButtonStyle}" Width="200" Margin="0, 15, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Panel.ZIndex="-1">Filter now</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

## Result Image

[image]

Comment: Your best bet would be to overwrite the Button's `Template`. You can place the Border on top of the Button, however the Button's corners would still stick out. They're not clipped with the Border's corner radius.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want.  Could you post a picture of what it should look like?

Comment: Do you want to change the look of the button? If so, just override its Template, as @Rachel said.

Comment: Can you post the Xaml for your MainBorderStyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your border has a corner radius, there isn't much you can do in the context of the button's default styling to round its corners to make it look seamless with the border. I have run into this issue with a few different controls, including buttons. The solution to your problem is to create a ControlTemplate for the button. Within this template you will be able to set the radius of the bottom corners of your button, or all 4 corners if you wish, to the matching corner radius of your border. Click [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2008/06/20/roundedbutton-button-style-wpf.aspx) for a good example of creating a rounded button template. Below I have attempted to simplify the blog code by removing the hover animation. Concentrate on the Border section as they are the main template.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundedButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">                        
            <Border 
                CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" 
                BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                x:Name="border" 
                BorderBrush="#000000">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                            <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                    <Border 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" 
                        x:Name="border1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush 
                                        EndPoint="0.5,1" 
                                        StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop 
                                            Color="#00FFFFFF" 
                                            Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop 
                                            Color="#7EFFFFFF" 
                                            Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>                                
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                                Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter 
                            Property="Opacity" 
                            TargetName="border1"  
                            Value="0.5"/>
                        <Setter 
                            Property="Opacity" 
                            TargetName="border" 
                            Value="1"/>
                        <Setter 
                            Property="Opacity" 
                            TargetName="contentPresenter" 
                            Value="0.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger 
                        Property="IsPressed" 
                        Value="True">
                        <Setter 
                            Property="RenderTransform" 
                            TargetName="border">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform 
                                        ScaleX="0.9" 
                                        ScaleY="0.9"/>
                                    <SkewTransform 
                                        AngleX="0" 
                                        AngleY="0"/>
                                    <RotateTransform 
                                        Angle="0"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform 
                                        X="0" 
                                        Y="0"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Also, here is a link to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) page regarding this subject.

Comment: When using the example above the button functionality (clicks and so on) is gone. Is there an easy way to just add the default functionality or do I have to implement them all like the example on MSDN?

Comment: sorry. Just realised that all the event are being called. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ZIndex` property to move the button down the border

Try this

```
<Button Name="filterCustomerBtn" 
Command="{Binding Path=UpdateDepartments}" 
Style="{StaticResource defaultButtonStyle}" 
Width="200" 
Margin="0, 15, 0, 0" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center" Panel.ZIndex="-1">Filter now</Button>
```

Comment: Intellisense won't work. Try to write above line and then compile the code

Comment: It doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Yes I can do that too... 2 sek

Answer (score 0):

You want the button to *below the border*...but you have it as *content* inside the border. That won't work..

Put the border in  a grid with two rows and two columns, have the border and its content on a row which spans both columns, then the button on a different row first column, then **margin** the button up to the location on the border where you want it. Here is an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="348*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="155*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}"
        Margin="2"
        Height="100"
        Background="LightBlue"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Nothing" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
<Button Name="filterCustomerBtn"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Command="{Binding Path=UpdateDepartments}"
        Width="100"
        Height="24"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Margin="0,-55,5,0"
        Panel.ZIndex="100">Filter now</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think they mean that the button edges show above the border line.

Comment: That is right - you missed my question. I want to button to be behind the border. Like photoshops layers

Comment: Ok...but what is the point of a button behind a border? Why not draw the button like a border then?

Comment: It is because I want the button to fill in the buttom of a border. I will upload a result image in 2 minutes